# shows err_connection_timed_out when I try to see my react app on mobile

Tags: reactjs, mobile, terminal

I want to test my react app on my smartphone.

I am not using react native because I haven't learned that yet.

[image]

As you see, port number is 8080.

What I tried to run my app on mobile:

tried iconfig in terminal and got my IPv4 address.

[image]

after that, typed my ipv4 address:8080 in my mobile chrome browser.
Something like that:

192.1xx.x.xxx:8080

but shows err_connection_timed_out error.

On the other hand, I can connect to 192.1xx.x.xxx/dashboard. It works fine.

Can't understand why I can't run my react app on my mobile browser if I can connect to xampp dashboard.

And of course, my smartphone and pc are using same wifi.

Comment: wow only 3 viewers... is my problem so difficult to solve?

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `webpack-dev-server` and running app on localhost. you will not be able to run your app over the network, i dont know why, but thats how it behaves. 
instead you can build you application. and run a `python` server or `nodejs` server in your dist folder, then it will work over your local network.

if you have `python 2.7` you can run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9090` in your build dist folder. to start a server on port 9090.

Comment: Ok.. so u mean I need move from webpack server to python or nodejs?Oh no that's a big problem..

Comment: no no.. webpack devserver is used for fast development on local machine.. build your code with webpack.. webpack will emit files for u.. usually in `dist` folder. in that folder you can run python server. bdw are u using create react app ?

Comment: No sadly.. I am not using CRA. I have my own webpack.config.js

Comment: thats even better.. do you have your build script ? or script for that builds for production.

Comment: I haven't done anything about production.. but the first question.. which script do you mean? webpack.config.js ? package.json?

Comment: there is a command to build your code for production. which runs you webpack.config in production env. thus emiting files which can be deployed on any server. read [this](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/)